# What purpose does the colon builtin ':' serve?

Tags: shell-script, shell-builtin

I've hacked on a lot of shell scripts, and sometimes the simplest things baffle me. Today I ran across a script that made extensive use of the `:` (colon) bash builtin.

The [documenation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) seems simple enough:

> ```
> : (a colon)  
>      : [arguments]
> ```
>
> Do nothing beyond expanding arguments and performing redirections. The return status is zero.

However I have previously only seen this used in demonstrations of shell expansion. The use case in the script I ran across made extensive use of this structure:

```
if [ -f ${file} ]; then
    grep some_string ${file} >> otherfile || :
    grep other_string ${file} >> otherfile || :
fi
```

There were actually hundreds of greps, but they are just more of the same. No input/output redirects are present other than  the simple structure above. No return values are checked later in the script.

I am reading this as a useless construct that says "or do nothing". What purpose could ending these greps with "or do nothing" serve? In what case would this construct cause a different outcome than simply leaving off the `|| :` from all instances?

Comment: One possible purpose I can see is to use `:` as an alternative to `true`.  Perhaps `errexit` is set and the author doesn't care about the exit status of some commands.

Comment: Heh, [nearly identical question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin)

Comment: the Stackoverflow linked page is IMO a little more comprehensive (so good to read both this page and the linked page).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It appears the `:`s in your script are being used in lieu of `true`. If `grep` doesn't find a match in the file, it will return a nonzero exit code; as jw013 mentions in a comment, if `errexit` is set, probably by `-e` on the shebang line, the script would exit if any of the `grep`s fail to find a match. Clearly, that's not what the author wanted, so (s)he added `|| :` to make the exit status of that particular compound command always zero, like the more common (in my experience) `|| true`/`|| /bin/true`.

Comment: Duh. This was in the concept of an RPM build script, and while I didn't see any exit code checking inside the script, I forgot to consider that the parent process might be watching.

Comment: If that's the case, I'd call it poor scripting practice.  It's functionally equivalent to using `true` instead, but the semantic intent is much clearer with `true`.  `:` is more suitable when an explicit NOP is desired.

Comment: In my experience, this is a common practice in RPM scripts. It probably shouldn't be, but there we are.

Comment: some purists prefer `:` instead of `true` because `:` is a `bash` built-in where as `true` is usually a compiled binary with more overhead. usually i use `true` because the code is more readable (likewise I prefer to use `source` instead of `.`).

Comment: @jw013 `:` as true is known because of `while :; do`... it's extremely common knowledge abong bash users and just as good practice as ternary operators. I'm here because I saw it being used in the way @Joni is using it.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith, Bash 3.2 already has `true` as a builtin. Busybox does say that `:` is a "special shell builtin" and `true` a (regular) "shell builtin", but I'm not sure what the difference would be, at least here.

Answer (score 54):

The `:` builtin is also useful with the Bash "assign default values" shell expansion, where the expansion is often used solely for the side effect and the value expanded is thrown away:

```
# assign FOO=bar iff FOO is unset or empty
: "${FOO:=bar}"
```

Comment: Came here looking for this, was baffled when I saw this pattern in a script to declare default values.

Answer (score 28):

The `:` built-in was already in the [Thompson shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_shell) — it's [documented](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/1/sh) for [Unix V6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_6_Unix) in 1975. In the Thompson shell, `:` indicated a label for the [`goto`](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/1/goto) command. If you never attempted to call `goto` on a line beginning with `:` , that line was effectively a comment.

The [Bourne shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell), the ancestor of Bourne/POSIX shells as we know them, never had a `goto` that I know of, but retained `:` as a no-op command (it was already present in [Unix V7](http://cm.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/)), and it was commonly used for comments (an actual comment syntax with `#` was only added in a later version).

Comment: Point for informative historical background.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the Bourne shell initially didn't have `# comments` which were introduced by csh. csh does still support labels (though that's with `label:` instead of `: label`, but that still means `:` defines an empty goto label). See also [Difference between cat and '>' to zero out a file](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/131024)

Answer (score 24):

I can think of two places I've used `:` in the past.

```
while :
do
     shell commands
     some exit condition
done
```

That is a forever-loop.

```
function doSomethingStub {
    :
}
```

Put in a stub function, just to get top level flow of control correct.

One use I've seen back in the Old Days: Instead of a `#!/bin/sh` (or whatever) line, you'd see a `:` line. Some of the older Real Unix kernels or Real Unix shells would use that to mean "I'm a shell script, have sh run me". As I recall this was just when csh was making inroads as a common interactive shell. See: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-16.html

Comment: @BruceEdiger: Do you have a reference to the "shecolon" line?

Comment: Finally found a ": at the beginning of a script" reference and explanation: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-16.html

Comment: the behavior at the start with `:` is very strange. i found that it does indeed cause the script to be run with `sh`. where as when you start the script without a shebang... it tries to run the script with whatever shell is running (so if you are running `bash` it tries to run it as `bash` if you have `csh` then it tries to run it as `csh`).

Answer (score 19):

I dug out an old reference: "The UNIX Programming Environment" (c) 1984 by Kernighan and Pike.

Page 147 (Shell Programming) says this:

> > ":" is a shell built-in command that does nothing but evaluate its arguments and return "true".  Instead [referring to a script example], we could have used **true**, which merely returns a true exit status.  (There is also a **false** command.)  But ':' is more efficient than true *because it does not execute a command from the file system*. [Italics/emphasis is mine.]

Comment: Of course, `true` is now a shell builtin, too, on many systems.

Answer (score 15):

":" is handy for debugging.

```
DEBUGLOG=": debugfunction"

statement
statement
$DEBUGLOG arg1 arg2 ...
statement
statement
```

Running normally the debugfunction is never executed so sh just steps over the noop (variables and wildcards are expanded though). If more in depth debugging is required, remove the noop from the variable and debugfunction is called with whatever arguments are required.

Another handy use is as a block comment, which is a missing feature from shell syntax.

```
: << COMMENT
all --statements --in --here
are now -a here document which are
passed to --the noop
COMMENT
```

Answer (score 9):

I seem to recall that early versions of the shell didn't have a comment syntax.  A line starting with `:` (which probably would have been an actual executable, similar to `/bin/true`) would have been the best alternative.

Here's a [man page](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/sh) for the ancient [Thompson shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_shell) (no relation); there's no mention of any comment syntax.

Comment: The origin of `:` was in fact a label indicator for the `goto` command, in some ancient shell (I don't know which). A label `: something` could indeed be used as a comment, if there was no matching `goto`. The practice stuck even after `goto` disappeared.