# What is the difference between : and true?

Tags: bash, dash

In `bash`:

```
$ type :
: is a shell builtin
$ type true
true is a shell builtin
```

Looks like they are the same, but they don't give the same system trace:

```
$ strace :
strace: :: command not found
$ strace true
execve("/bin/true", ["true"], [/* 82 vars */]) = 0
[snip]
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

I tried diffing `strace bash -c : 2>:.txt` and `strace bash -c true 2>true.txt`, but couldn't find any differences between them except for the memory locations.

In `dash`:

```
$ type :
: is a special shell builtin
$ type true
true is a shell builtin
```

OK, so they are not the same. `help :` and `help true` aren't very useful, and they return the same in `bash` and `dash`. Is there any practical difference at all between them, except that `:` saves three bytes and makes scripts less readable?

Comment: Related [question about the purpose of the colon builtin](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31673/what-purpose-does-the-colon-builtin-serve).

Comment: See also [Which is more idiomatic in a bash script: \`|| true\` or \`|| :\`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78408)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's no real difference in behavior.  Both commands do nothing and exit with a successful status.  `:` emphasizes doing nothing; `true` emphasizes the successful status.

`strace true` works because `true` is both a shell builtin and an external command (`/bin/true`); `:` is only a shell builtin (there's no `/bin/:` -- though there could be, and probably was on very old Unix systems).  In bash, try

```
type -a :
type -a true
```

The reasons that both exist are historical.  If I recall correctly, some very early shells didn't have a comment syntax, so the do-nothing `:` command was used instead.

There is some internal difference in `dash`.  Looking through the source, available at git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git, shows some different code paths in `eval.c`, but I haven't been able to produce any visibly different behavior other than the word `special` in the output of `type :`.

Comment: Additionally, early versions of UNIX did not have `/bin/true` or `/bin/false`.  Also the `:` command is sometimes used for the argument processing side effects: `: ${num_times:=10}`.

Comment: `:` was [originally a label indicator](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19124/bash-multi-line-command-with-comments-after-the-continuation-character/19126#19126), back in an ancestor of the Bourne shell that had `goto`. Apparently `:` was abused as a comment indicator and stuck.

Comment: The behavior of `:` as a label indicator for goto was preserved in Microsoft's pseudo-Unix command line clone, `command.com`, and remains in its successor `cmd.exe`, as does the practice of abusing `::` for a line comment.

Answer (score 8):

They're identical in Bash. Look at `builtins/colon.def` in the Bash-4.2 source code.

In your command `strace true` you are actually running the binary `/bin/true` instead of the bash built-in true.

Answer (score 6):

The difference between the commands are that by definition `:` is a **special built-in** utility whereas `true` is a **regular built-in** utility in POSIX compliant shells.

[According to POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14), **special built-ins** are treated slightly differently in a way that:

> variable assignments preceding the invocation of a special built-in
> utility remain in effect after the built-in completes; this shall not
> be the case with a regular built-in or other utility.

This can be illustrated in POSIX compliant shells as follows:

```bash
$ VAR=FOO
$ VAR=BAR :
$ echo "$VAR"
BAR
```

```bash
$ VAR=FOO
$ VAR=BAR true
$ echo "$VAR"
FOO
```

Another aspect of difference is that:

> an error in a special built-in utility may cause a shell executing
> that utility to abort, while an error in a regular built-in utility
> shall not cause a shell executing that utility to abort.

Example code in action:

```bash
$ ( : > ""; echo "You won't see this!" )
sh: 1: cannot create : Directory nonexistent
$  echo "Exit code: $?"
Exit code: 2
```

```bash
$ ( true > ""; echo "Hello!" )
sh: 1: cannot create : Directory nonexistent
Hello!
$ echo "Exit code: $?"
Exit code: 0
```

Comment: That's a useful distinction. I've even seen it in action, in a very confusing form, to avoid duplication when setting default values: [`: "${VARIABLE:=DEFAULT_VALUE}"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28085062/96588).

Comment: @l0b0, using `${var:=value}` is unrelated, though, it'd work with `true` also. (Try e.g. `unset foo; true "${foo:=value}"; echo $foo` with `true` vs. `:`.) The standard text only mentions variable assignments before the command --those that would end up as env vars for the launched command-- not expansions within the command line.

Comment: See also `sh  -c ': > /; echo x'` vs `sh  -c 'true > /; echo x'` and [Which is more idiomatic in a bash script: \`|| true\` or \`|| :\`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78411)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Updated my answer to include this aspect too. Thank you!