# Which is more idiomatic in a bash script: `|| true` or `|| :`?

Tags: bash, shell

I don't do terribly much shell scripting, so I was a little surprised when I was reading [the documentation for `git submodule`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html) and I saw the syntax they used in this documentation:

> A non-zero return from the command in any submodule causes the processing to terminate. This can be overridden by adding `|| :` to the end of the command.

I had to look up that `|| :` was a shorthand for forcing a command to exit successfully.  Anytime I've had to make a command exit successfully, I used `|| true`.  Is `|| :` considered to be more idiomatic?

Comment: It's worth noting that `||:` (with no space) is also valid in bash. It does the same thing as `|| :` or `|| true`.

Answer (score 63):

`true` was not built into the Bourne shell. `:` always was (it was the way to enter comments before `#` was introduced).

That, and because it's shorter to type is probably the main reason people prefer `:` over `true`.

Note another difference in POSIX shells (for `bash`, only in POSIX mode): while `true` is a regular builtin (doesn't even have to be builtin), `:` is a *special* builtin. That has a few implications, most of which are unlikely to have any impact in this particular case:

- If a `:` command fails, including because of a failed redirection, that causes the shell to exit. In practice, that probably won't make a difference unless you pass redirections to `:`

  ```
  $ sh -c ': > /   ; echo HERE'
  sh: 1: cannot create /: Is a directory
  $ sh -c 'true > /; echo HERE'
  sh: 1: cannot create /: Is a directory
  HERE
  ```
- in `var=value :`, `var` remains set to `value` after `:` returns, not in the case of `true`:

  ```
  $ var=1; var=2 :   ; echo "$var"
  2
  $ var=1; var=2 true; echo "$var"
  1
  ```

Also note that `|| true` works in shells of the `rc` and `csh` families but not `|| :` (but not to cancel `set -e` in `csh`).

`|| :` is not the same as `:`. It means *or run `:` otherwise* (that is, if the preceding pipeline fails).

```
set -e
false
```

Would cause the shell to exit because of `set -e` (aka the `errexit` option) and `false` has a non-zero (failure) exit status. The `set -e` effect is cancelled if the command that returns a non-zero exit status is used as a *condition* like in:

```
if false; then ...
while false; do ...
false && : ...
false || : ...
```

`false && :` only cancels `set -e`. `false || :` cancels the effect of `set -e` and sets the exit status to `0` so is more idiomatic to say that we want to ignore a failure exit code of the command. Most would argue that `|| true` is more legible (conveys the intention more clearly).

Comment: `&& :` is brilliant, are there any docs or further reading on this? Google falls short on me trying to find this sort of keywords…

Comment: @IanBytchek, check your shell's manual. See `info bash set` for bash or `info zsh errexit` for `zsh` or `set --help 2>&1 | pager` for ksh93 for instance.

Answer (score 13):

Most of these responses fail to address the most common use of `:`.

First, this discussion is not related to any shell that is not a [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) (`sh`) derivative. That said, all Bourne derivative shells see `true` and `:` as the same thing. Programmers used to be encouraged to use `:` instead of `true`, because `:` is always a built-in while there used to be cases where `true` was not always a built-in.

`:` has two uses. It is not a synonym for `#`, but it has a different function. When debugging your script under a `set -x`, lines where `#` is used are dropped by the parser and totally ignored, whereas lines with `:` are parsed and evaluated. This is really useful in debugging since under `-x` those lines are shown and their value after evaluation are displayed. It is like putting `print` statements in your code that only show under `-x` mode. Be careful with the values after the `:` since they are real code and the side-effects can affect your program.

Comment: What is the second use?

Answer (score 8):

Generally, in bash, the colon `:` and `true` is equivalent.

> Is || : considered to be more idiomatic?

I think it is based on the **context**.

If you want a `return value`, or a `condition` is always true, you should use `true` keyword, it's will make your code more clearly and let the viewers know that you want emphasize the value **true**, i.e:

```
while true; do something
```

or

```
<commnad>
RETURN_VALUE= $? || true
```

And if you want to **do nothing**, or `NOP` in shell, you should use colon `:`

```
if condition
then
    : # DO NOTHING HERE
else
    do something
fi
```

or

```
while conditon
do
    : # DO NOTHING HERE
done
```