# Make error when executing recipe with conditional operator

Tags: linux, make

My Makefile is very simple:

```
all:
      [ -f MyFile ] && echo "MyFile exists"
```

Of course the recipe line begins with tab. If the file MyFile really exists, everything is ok. But if this file is not in the current directory I get:

Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1

I can get rid of this error using the if statement instead:

```
all:
      if [ -f MyFile ]; then echo "MyFile exists"; fi
```

Both statements work fine in sh and bash outside make. It is unclear for me what is the reason of the make error when the conditional operator is used. An ideas what is going on?

Comment: The line you are talking about is called command line in the standard and in the documentation of all `make` implementations except `gmake`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[ -f MyFile ] && echo "MyFile exists"
```

exits with a non-zero status code if `MyFile` doesn’t exist, whereas

```
if [ -f MyFile ]; then echo "MyFile exists"; fi
```

exits with a successful (zero) status code unless `MyFile` exists *and* `echo` fails with a write error.

Make relies on status codes to determine whether commands failed, and it stops execution by default when any command fails. You can disable this for individual command lines by prefixing them with `-`, or overall by running `make -i` or by specifying the special `.IGNORE` target. Thus

```
-[ -f MyFile ] && echo "MyFile exists"
```

would both allow Make to continue, but would still cause it to print a message if `MyFile` doesn’t exist:

> make: [Makefile:14: test] Error 1 (ignored)

[The `|| true` pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325727/86440) would also work in this specific case, but it would ignore errors in `echo`. `if condition; then command; fi` won’t cause Make to stop if `condition` is false, but will take `command`’s errors into account, whereas `condition && command || true` will ignore all errors.

Comment: @pizdelect good point; I mentioned the specific `|| true` pattern instead of the more general `|| cmd2` pattern, but that does result in errors being ignored.