# What is the purpose of "|| true" in Tumbleweed's .bashrc?

Tags: bash

openSUSE Tumbleweed has

```
test -s ~/.alias && . ~/.alias || true
```

as the contents of its `~/.bashrc`.

The way I understand the part to the left of `|| true` is that

- there's a check to see if `~/.alias` exists and has a size greater than zero.
- and, if the conditions are met, the file is sourced.

So why is `|| true` necessary?

---

GNU bash, version 5.0.16(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|| true` is useful in contexts where we don’t care if the command fails; in this particular case, if `~/.alias` doesn’t exist, `test -s` will fail with a non-zero exit code, but we don’t want that to have any other consequence. `|| true` ensures that the full command list (including sourcing `~/.alias`) always exits with a successful status.

This would be particularly relevant if the `.bashrc` included `set -e`, although that would be unusual for a shell startup script.

Another way to write this would be

```
if test -s ~/.alias; then . ~/.alias; fi
```

but that would exit with a non-zero exit code if sourcing `~/.alias` caused an error.

See also [Why is pattern "command || true" useful?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/325705/86440)

Answer (score 1):

The `|| true` ensures that the whole command returns a "Success" status,  even if `./.aliases` returns non-zero (Failure) status.

Handy if you're using `set -e` (exit on error).