# What does "[ "$foo_user" = 'foo' ] && foo_user='bar' || true" do?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I found this line in one of our repositories without any comments explaining what it does.  I am fixing a bug that I found in this repository and don't know what to make of this line.  I am unsure of how to research for this in a time efficient manner, so I'm asking here.

```bsh
[ "$foo_user" = 'foo' ] && foo_user='bar' || true
```

It looks like an if statement that tests if `$foo_user='foo'` then return true, and then sets `foo_user` to "bar" if it is not set?  I really have no idea what to make of this.

What does this code do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s split it up:

```
[ "$foo_user" = 'foo' ]
```

checks whether the `foo_user` variable’s value is “foo”.

```
&& foo_user='bar'
```

runs if the previous command succeeded (`&&`); thus if `foo_user`’s value is “foo”, it is set to “bar” instead.

```
|| true
```

runs if the previous command failed (`||`); thus, in all cases, the compound command (in this case, the complete line) succeeds. This pattern is commonly seen when `set -e` is enabled (even though it isn’t actually necessary).

See also [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/86440), [Precedence of the shell logical operators &&, ||](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88850/86440), and [Why is pattern "command || true" useful?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/325705/86440)

Comment: In this case, a `set -e` would not matter as this is and/or list. However, it would matter in a Makefile, for example, or in any other setting where the exit status of individual pipelines/commands matter.

Comment: Good point, because the exit code is checked. However it is still commonly seen because many shell developers think that `|| true` is necessary in such circumstances ;-).