# When to use "|| true" in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I was curious about "`|| true`" and wrote the following pair of examples.

#### Example#1

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    
    rm some_random_file_that_does_not_exist
    
    echo "End of program"
```

When executed if produces the following result:

```
$ ./remove.sh
rm: cannot remove 'some_random_file_that_does_not_exist': No such file or directory
End of program
```

#### Example#2

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rm some_random_file_that_does_not_exist || true

echo "End of program"
```

Which produces the following result when executed:

```
$ ./remove.sh
rm: cannot remove 'some_random_file_that_does_not_exist': No such file or directory
End of program
```

The only difference I can tell is that in Example#1 the result code of the line that tries to remove the non-existent file is 1 while in Example#2 the result code is 0 (zero).

The way I understand this "`|| true`" is to ensure that the execution of the command(s) at the left of the "`||`" operator ends up with result code zero.

So my question is... Is there any other reason apart from this one that justifies the use of "`|| true`" at the end of a command in Bash?

Comment: Related: [Which is more idiomatic in a bash script: \`|| true\` or \`|| :\`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78408)

Comment: This isn't the original question, but you would be much better off just using `rm -f some_random_file_that_does_not_exist`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`|| true` may be used to suppress immediate exit on error when the `errexit` shell option is set; that option is enabled with `set -e`, either by `set -e` explicitly in the script, or by invoking the script with an explicit interpreter and options: `bash -e scriptname`. In `sh`-like shells like `bash`, `:` (a utility that does nothing, successfully) may also be used in place of `true`, like `|| :`.

It may also be used in Makefile recipes with the same purpose.

Comment: `||:` should work in any POSIX shell, both the `||` operator and the `:` command are standard. (And whatever the minor differences between `:` and `true` were, they're not relevant here.) Though I'd rather write `|| true` than `||:`, as especially without the space in between, the latter seems unnecessarily obfuscated.

Comment: Regarding usage in Makefile, GNU make supports `-` prefix to ignore command failure but i also have seen `|| true`. Maybe it was for portability, i'm not sure about other implementations.

Comment: @dimich I'm pretty sure I was using that in makefiles long before GNU make was mainstream. I think this was from SysV.3 or BSD era, if not earlier

Comment: Stuart Feldman’s original `make` supported `-`, I don’t think I’ve ever come across an implementation that didn’t.

Comment: Many programmers don't known `make` so well, so they may just use what they know (so shell syntax, which works).

Comment: The `-` prefix is definitely more idiomatic in makefiles. But you might need to use `||true` if you have a multi-line recipe and you need to ignore intermediate errors.