# How do I use the "if" command for multiple conditions?

Tags: bash

How do I do this?

```
if [ -f town-*.swf ]
then
mkdir towns
fi
```

This checks if `town-*.swf` exists, but I also need it to look for `city-*.swf` among others, so I need something like this:

```
if [ -f town-*.swf, city-*.swf ]
then
mkdir towns
fi
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to build a switch-case for this?

Comment: Whats a "switch-case"?

Comment: See here: http://www.shellhacks.com/en/CASE-Statement-in-Bash-Example

Comment: @ryekayo `case` can (and often should) be used for testing equality or matching, but how do you want to use `case` to check whether a file exists?

Comment: @DisplayName Just for clarification: Do you assume that there is at most one file matching each of the patterns `town-*.swf` and `city-*.swf`, or could there be several ones?

Comment: @DisplayName Still the question is whether there *can* be several files, say `town-1.swf` and `town-2.swf`? (If it's impossible, there's an easy solution; if it's possible, you have to work harder.)

Comment: There could be several files too.

Comment: @DisplayName, please see the updated answer and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POSIXly, you can use `ls`

```
if ls town-*.swf >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
   ls city-*.swf >/dev/null 2>&1 
then
  mkdir towns
fi
```

or shorter if condition:

```
if ls town-*.swf city-*.swf >/dev/null 2>&1
```

even if your shell supports [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
if ls {town,city}-*.swf >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if stat -t city-*.swf >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    if stat -t town-*.swf >/dev/null 2>&1
    then
       mkdir towns
    fi
fi
```

As user uwe pointed out in the comments, my previous command would prevent the wild card from being expanded. However, this new version should work.

If you need it with a single `if` loop, you could modify the script as,

```
if stat -t city-*.swf >/dev/null 2>&1 && stat -t town-*.swf >/dev/null 2>&1
then
     mkdir towns
fi
```

If you need to specify an or condition instead of the and condition, you could replace `&&` with `||`.

**Testing**

```
ls
city-1.swf  city-2.swf  city-3.swf  city-4.swf  city-5.swf  sc.sh  
town-1.swf  town-2.swf  town-3.swf  town-4.swf  town-5.swf
```

Now, I execute the script which is named as `sc.sh` and then I could see that the **towns** directory is getting created successfully.

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash

Comment: @Uwe, thanks for pointing out. I have made the changes and this one works.

Comment: @Uwe, I have suggested the changes for specifying or condition.

Comment: It does create the directory without depending on them, what way would you do this counglm?

Comment: Yes but try it without the files too, and it will create the directory.

Comment: `if` is just a statement, not a loop.

Comment: This isn't portable and isn't a bash answer. `stat` works differently on different platforms. The `-t` option does something completely different in FreeBSD and OSX than it does in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases command `test ( [ )` offer operators `-a` and `-o`

> `EXPR1 -a EXPR2` True if both *expr1* AND *expr2* are true.
>   `EXPR1 -o EXPR2` True if either *expr1* OR *expr2* is true.

But in the case of possible multi-lines you should use command which can operate in the condition (for example `ls`)

```
ls {town,city}-*.swf &>/dev/null && mkdir town
```

You can use the fact that *globbing* when can't to find the substitution remain the string as is (in the case with `*`). So we just need to check is it somewhere in the line:

```
set -- {city,town}-*.swf 
[[ ! "$*" =~ \* ]] && mkdir town
```

Or use `case` (as offered in comments above)

```
case $(ls) in
  *city-*.swf*town-*.swf*) mkdir town ;;
esac
```

Comment: `find` was better. And you can always `-exec sh -c 'script'`. In there you might `kill find` and so only ever do one `-exec`. *(plus `ls` has been done already...)*

Comment: @mikeserv I'd like `find` too but in the case we need to check two conditions the command string can be rather difficult

Answer (score 1):

POSIX defines the `-p` option to the `pathchk` utility so...

- `-p` Instead of performing checks based on the underlying file system, write a diagnostic for each pathname operand that:

  - Is longer than {_POSIX_PATH_MAX} bytes (see Minimum Values in the Base Definitions volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, Chapter 13, Headers, )
  - Contains any component longer than {_POSIX_NAME_MAX} bytes
  - Contains any character in any component that is not in the portable filename character set

If the filenames you are looking for should match only characters in the *portable filename character set* - which is comprised of ASCII letters and digits and `._-/` - then the following command will work as well as any without having to do any more `stat()` calls than the shell does to glob them:

```
if    pathchk -p town-*.swf city-*.swf
then  mkdir towns
fi
```

Another way is to glob the pathname twice - once for an already known value and once also for the unknown. It the known value glob is not stripped then it is because the unknown value did not resolve.

Consider the following:

```
mkdir test
touch test/testfile1
echo tes[t]/test*1 tes[t]/test*2
```

#### OUTPUT

```
test/testfile1 tes[t]/test*2
```

Here we know the `test` path exists and so we can test for its resolution when attempting to match the unknown path's resolution.

For example, let's assume your current working directory is comprised entirely of pathnames that do not end with a `?` and there are no one-off paths that do either. This is not such a big assumption to make either - it can even be assured like:

```
cd /tmp/no_question_mark\? && {
    $_handle_it || exit
};  ln -s "$PWD" /tmp/no_question_marks
    cd /tmp/no_question_marks
```

That assumption made, you can then do something like:

```
set "${PWD%?}"?/town-*.swf "${PWD%?}"?/city-*.swf
case "$*" in (*\?/*) ! echo 'missed at least one...';;
(*) echo 'got em all!'; mkdir towns;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that's lower impact than running the external command `ls`, as well as being more portable than a solution based on `stat` (which differs from OS to OS).

```
#!/bin/bash

found=false
for _ in town-*.swf, city-*.swf do
  found=true; break
done

if $found; then
  echo "Yup!"
fi
```

The underscore is a throwaway variable.  The `for` loop is an easy way to expand your list of files, and the `break` insures that you won't waste cycles looping through a long file list.  The executables `true` and `false` can be found in `/bin/` or `/usr/bin/`, and could be replaced with [bash builtins or functions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34677/what-is-the-difference-between-and-true) if you would prefer that optimization.

Note that this also should work in a `/bin/sh`.  (At least, it did for me in a couple of other operating systems.)